# Increasing value 1000 times through channels and goroutines

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I need to increase `x` 1000 times by creating 1000 goroutines which will increase the `x` by one through channels. How would I do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var ch = make(chan int)

    //1000 goroutines sending 1 through a channel
    var x = 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func() {
            ch <- 1
        }()
    }

    //Here i need to increase x by value read from the channel and then stop when the last value was sent
    //But this code doesn't work
    for {
        if v, ok := <-ch; ok {
            x += v
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

I was thinking about closing the channel at the end but I don't know how to detect when the last value was sent

Comment: The `for ... range` over a channel does exactly this: it receives all values sent on the channel, and terminates when the channel is closed (and all values sent before that are received). Also you must synchronize access to shared variables if accessed from multiple goroutines!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sync.WaitGroup` can be used for detecting the completion of a set of goroutines. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var ch = make(chan int)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    //1000 goroutines sending 1 through a channel
    var x = 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            ch <- 1
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    //Here i need to increase x by value read from the channel and then stop when the last value was sent
    //But this code doesn't work
    for {
        if v, ok := <-ch; ok {
            x += v
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

- [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/yDN9qnZnoYj)